# Differentiate under the sign of integral for composition with vector valued function

Tags: analysis, measure-theory, reference-request

I'm trying to find [proposition 4 of this link](https://web.archive.org/web/20160508220010/http://people.hss.caltech.edu/%7Ekcb/Notes/LeibnizRule.pdf) on a book or paper so I can use the result just citing it.

The result is the following

Let $(\Omega, F, \mu)$ be a measure space, let $A \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be open, and let the function $f : A\times\Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a Carathéodory function. Assume further that $f$ is locally uniformly integrably bounded. Then the function $g : A \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ defined by

$$
g(x) = \int_\Omega f(x, \omega) d\mu(\omega)
$$
is continuous.

Suppose further that for each $i$ and each $\omega$, the partial derivative $D_if(x, \omega)$ with respect to $x_i$ is a continuous function of $x$ and $D_if$ is locally uniformly integrably bounded. Then $g$ is continuously differentiable and
$$
D_ig(x) = \int_\Omega D_if(x, \omega) d\mu(\omega).
$$

Comment: What do you mean by "locally uniformly integrably bounded"?

Comment: It is the definition given by the PDF's author.)
The function $f : A\times\Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is locally uniformly integrably bounded if for every $x$ there
is a nonnegative measurable function $h_x : \Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, and a neighborhood $U_x$ of $x$ such that for all $y \in U_y, f(y, \omega) ⩽ h_x(\omega)$, and $ h_x$ is integrable, that is, $\int_\Omega h_x(\omega) dP(\omega) < \infty$.

Comment: all right this is reasonable. I have found "A Course on Integration Theory" by Nicolas Lerner, theorems 3.3.1 and 3.3.4

Comment: thank you very much